# Javascript pre-render Image not being displayed

Tags: javascript, image, rendering, invisible

I'm currently developping a html-page for ipad with a css3-transition slider for various contents.

The problem i encounter is, that images on the next page, which aren't rendered yet, will be rendered while sliding them to the content area (though they are preloaded).

Is there any way to make the Browser render them, without displaying them at initial page request, to prevent the stuttered sliding effect on images?

/EDIT:

Slider I use: [slider](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/)

structure is like:

```
<body>
    <!-- wrapper -->
    <div>
        <!-- head -->
        <div class="head"></div>
        <!-- content area -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="pagination"></div>
                <div class="slide-wrapper">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <!-- content with images here -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide"></div>
                    <div class="slide"></div>
                    <div class="slide"></div>
                    <div class="slide"></div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <!-- foot -->
        <div class="foot"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Image-Preloading:

```
function preload() {
    $('img').each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = $(this).attr('src');
    });
}
```

Comment: How are the pages structured? Share some code please.

Comment: Please show the code you use for preloading images.

Answer (score 2):

This will force browser to preload all images

```
$('img').each(function(){
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = $(this).attr('src')    

});
```

Answer (score 1):

A general technique is to set them as `visibility: hidden` (inline style to ensure it is applied even before any external CSS is downloaded) - And setting it to `visibility: visible` on `image.onload` handler.

`<img src="..." style="visibility: hidden" onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible';">`

---

**Edit**

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('<img/>')[0].src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).load(function() {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');        
    });
});
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. Would be great if it were that simple.

Comment: Didn't work as well. what I am going to do for now is let the slider slide vom start to end and backagain while having a transparent layer until its at the start again. thx for the effort so far!